# Caching Claims in .net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, claims-based-identity

Looked up everywhere but looks like I am stuck right now. I am using Windows Active Directory in my application for authentication. 
For authorization, I am using claims. After searching through the limited .net core documentation, this is how my code looks like.

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IPrincipal>(
            provider => provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User);
        services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();
        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    }
```

ClaimsTransformer.cs

```
class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
{
   public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
   {

// call to database to get more claims based on user id ClaimsIdentity.Name
     ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("now",DateTime.Now.ToString()));
     return Task.FromResult(principal);
   }
}
```

But the problem is, this code is called with every request and claims are loaded from the db every time which is absolutely wrong. Is there any way I can cache it? I was able to create a cookie of claims and use that cookie for any further calls in .net 4.0. I can't seem to find a way in the core. Any documentation I check, is incomplete or it does not cover my scenario. I am able to claims further in my application just how the documentation says here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims

But there is no mention about caching the claims.

Anyone in the same boat? Or knows the way out of it?

Comment: I'm wondering about this too.  I'll investigate the in-memory caching technique suggested by @Brad.  Though I don't like the inconsistency where a forms auth identity is cached in a cookie and a Windows auth identity is cached in memory.

Comment: @tanush A great question. I have exactly the same issue - database calls in my TransformAsync, and very poor official documentation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can inject the `IMemoryCache` service in your `ClaimsTransformer` constructor.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;

public class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;

    public ClaimsTransformer(IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }

    public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        var cacheKey = principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

        if (_cache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out List<Claim> claims)
        {
            ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaims(claims);
        }
        else
        {
            claims = new List<Claim>();          

            // call to database to get more claims based on user id ClaimsIdentity.Name

            _cache.Set(cacheKey, claims);
        }

        return principal;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising. I'll try this out and see how it goes. Thanks for providing a new perspective. I was stuck in the whole cookie and session thing from my .net 4.0 code.

Comment: Worked. Had to change itsy bit of code to make it work, but this is the working solution.

Comment: Could you provide your full solution with the bits of code that you changed? I am currently looking at a ClaimsTransformer for Windows Authentication

Comment: @mheptinstall who are you asking?

Comment: Sorry should have included @tanush in my comment

Comment: @mheptinstall This: https://codepaste.net/x2v13f. It's pretty much the same code. Used DI to get claims from Db

Comment: Well praise be! Works for me, I've been meaning to fix those recurring db calls since forever! I always thought I should write the additional claims to cookie but I don't suppose there is much perf diff with this method.

Answer (score 0):

I am not doing the exact same thing, but I am using cookie Authentication/Authorization.  Most of what I learned comes from [this microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x) but as you said the documentation doesn't seem to take you all the way there.  Here is what is working for me:

in startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...

        services.AddAuthentication("tanushCookie")
        .AddCookie("tanushCookie", options => {
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/api/Auth/Forbidden";
            options.LoginPath = "/";
            options.Cookie.Expiration = new TimeSpan(7,0,0,0);
        });
    }


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
                      IHostingEnvironment env, 
                      ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        ...

        app.UseAuthentication();
    }
```

And then in your controller that handles authentication:

```
    [HttpPost()]
    [Route("api/[Controller]/[Action]/")]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Login([FromBody]Dictionary<string, string> loginData)
    {
        try
        {
            var loggedIn = true;
            if (loggedIn)
            {
                var claims = new List<Claim> {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "tanush")
                };

                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                identity.AddClaims(claims);
                ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                    "tanushCookie",
                    principal,
                    new AuthenticationProperties
                    {
                        IsPersistent = true,
                        ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7)
                    });
            }
            return new JsonResult(logRtn);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new JsonResult(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I am unsure if you can use cookies with windows authentication.  However if you can authenticate and assign loggedIn the result of your authentication request, you should be able to store some sort of claim(s) in the cookie. You can then recall that claim in a controller that might be doing authorization/recalling values using the following:

```
    [HttpGet("[Action]", Name = "GetSomething")]
    [Route("[Action]")]
    public JsonResult something()
    {
        try
        {
            var loggedInUser = HttpContext.User;
            var claym = loggedInUser.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Name);
            if (claym != null)
            {
                return new JsonResult(claym.Value);
                // returns "tanush"
            }
            else
            {
                return new JsonResult("");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new JsonResult(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem with windows authentication is that it does not have any a controller which handles the authentication. Although it makes me think, I can add a middleware for windows authentication and add the claims their rather than in claims transformer. Thanks for your help.